# Как запустить файл через определенную программу?

Tags: python, subprocess, psutil

Есть файл который нужно открыть с помощью определенной программы. Как это сделать через subprocess?

Например, файл file.txt по умолчанию открывается через блокнот. Как сделать так, чтобы он открывался через app.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о том, чтобы в программе на Python запустить приложение, которое откроет файл, то всё просто, запускаете приложение, и указываете имя файла так, как приложение ожидает его получить, обычно это просто первый из параметров командной строки. Например, если из командной строки вы бы запустили приложение таким образом:

```
app.exe file.txt
```

То через subprocess нужно было бы сделать так:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["app.exe", "test.txt"])
```

Сделаю оговорку, что проверял под Linux, но вряд ли в этом случае под Windows будут какие-либо отличия.